# How to pre-compute Gas requirement of a function to avoid metamask error

Tags: contract-design, gas

How can we pre-compute Gas needed for successful execution of a function inside a smart contract. I got to know about web3.eth.estimateGas but cannot follow it completely from the docs.

My function receives some input parameters, calls Oraclize and then updates data in mappings inside the contract. My understanding is that in order to calculate gas estimate, value of input parameters must be used every time. What is the correct way to calculate gas estimates in this scenario, please help..

```
   function createProof (string _title, string _ipfshash, string 
    _proofremarks, string _prooftags)
    payable public {        
    /*** Some Logic ***/
   /// Call Oraclize to get current timestamp
   update();
    }
```

Comment: `estimateGas` is indeed the right way. Perhaps you could show us the code where  you're trying to get the gas estimate and call the function.

Comment: @Smarx below is my function to estimate Gas: 
function howmuchgas(params, fileId) {
const gasEstimate = Blockproof.createProof.estimateGas((params["title"], fileId, params["remarks"], params["tags"]),{ from: web3.eth.accounts[0] } );  console.log(gasEstimate);}. Here Blockproof is the name of my contract and createProof is the name of my function whose gas I wish to estimate. On running this code I am getting ' Cannot read property 'estimateGas' of undefined' in my Chrome Browser Console.

Comment: Which version of `web3.js` are you using? According to the error, `Blockproof.createProof` is undefined.

Comment: I am using "web3": "^0.20.7", and no web3.js. Also have used below commands in my app.js to access the contract abi json  import blockproof_artifacts from "../../build/contracts/Blockproof.json";     const Blockproof = contract(blockproof_artifacts); import { default as Web3 } from "web3";

Comment: You need to u se an instance of the contract, like you would to actually call the function. E.g. `const  blockproofInstance = BlockProof.at('0x1234...')`

Comment: Can you please help provide some sample code which implements above logic ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. I don't know your contract's address, so I can't give you a better line of code than the one I already gave. :-)

Comment: I created instance of the contract and now I am getting metamask error in chrome browser console: Uncaught (in promise) Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_estimateGas without a callback parameter.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass a callback. :-) `blockproofInstance.createProof.estimateGas("foo", "bar", "baz", "blah", function (err, result) { if (err) { console.log("ERROR: " + err); } else { console.log(result); });`

Comment: just solved it...thanks a lot for your help throughout the day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81860/discussion-between-tanmay-and-smarx).